# Finding the action of a discretized Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, discrete

I am trying to find the action associated with the Lagrangian density
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}   \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2. \tag{1} $$
I am supposed to use the discrete expansions
$$\phi_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Na}}\sum_p \tilde{\phi}_pe^{ipja} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{Na}}\sum_{-p} \tilde{\phi}_{-p}e^{-ipja}. \tag{2}   $$

So, first I find the Lagrangian, using
$$ L = \int dx \mathcal{L} =   a  \sum_j \mathcal{L} = \frac{a}{2}\sum_j \left[ \left( \frac{\phi_{j+1}-\phi_j}{a} \right)^2 + m^2\phi_j^2 \right]  \tag{3}  $$
where $j$ labels the 1D lattice sites and $a$ is the equilibrium distance between each site.
Now I plug in the expansion for $\phi_j$ into the Lagrangian, and where $\phi_j$ is squared, I use one copy of the middle ($+p$) term in eq (2) and one copy of the right ($-p$) term in eq (2), multiplied together.  This is motivated by the form of the action I am supposed to get in the end.
When I do the substitution into $L$, I end up with
$$ L = \frac{1}{2} \sum_p \tilde{\phi_p}\tilde{\phi_{-p}}\left[ \frac{2}{a^2}\left(  1-\cos{pa}  \right)  +m^2   \right]  \tag{4}.    $$

Now to get the action, I know that 
$$ S = \int L dt, \tag{5}$$ but I have no idea where time is supposed to come into this problem at all.  When integrating the Lagrangian density to get the Lagrangian, I know that I had to realize that the integral over one spatial dimension becomes, in the discrete case, a sum over the positions $x_j$ times the lattice constant $a$, or just a sum over $j$, again times $a$.  In addition, the spatial derivative in the Lagrangian becomes a discrete difference, as I have shown above.

Furthermore, the expression that I obtained for the Lagrangian $L$ is exactly what my textbook says I should obtain for the action $S$!  Is this somehow the result of the problem not having any obvious time-dependence?  **So, in total, I suppose I want to know how the action relates to the Lagrangian in the case of a problem that doesn't involve time.**

Just for clarity, I am going to write the question as phrased in the textbook (QFT for the Gifted Amateur):

> *Exercise 17.5 (a):* Consider a one-dimensional system with Lagrangian
>   $$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x}     \right)^2 + \frac{m^2}{2} \left[ \phi(x)  \right]^2. $$
>   The choice of sign makes this a Euclidean theory.  Descretize this theory (that is, put it on a lattice) by defining 
>   $$ \phi_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Na}} \sum_p \tilde{\phi}_p e^{ipja},    $$
>   where $j$ labels the lattice site, $a$ is the lattice spacing, and $N$ is the number of lattice points.  Using the method in exercise 17.3 show that the action may be written
>   $$ S = \frac{1}{2} \sum_p \tilde{\phi}_{-p} \left( \frac{2}{a^2}-\frac{2}{a^2}\cos{pa} + m^2    \right) \tilde{\phi}_p,   $$
>   and read off the propagator for this theory.

The "method in exercise 17.3" is just what I described in between eq (3) and eq (4), where you expand $\phi_j$ in terms of its Fourier transforms $\tilde{\phi}_p$ and $\tilde{\phi}_{-p}$.  Problem 17.3 also is the one that shows that the free propagator is $\frac{i}{2}$ times the inverse of the quadratic term in the momentum-space action, which is why this problem is asking us to find the action in the first place.

Comment: @Qmechanic: His question says nothing about the continuum limit.

Comment: Wouldn't taking the limit as $a$ goes to zero just be undoing the discretization that I was told to implement?

Comment: @MarkMitchison I added an exact copy of the problem at the end of my question.  The Lagrangian density given seems to indicate that $\phi$ is just a function of x, not of x,t.

Comment: The question (v5) seems to be caused by a somewhat misleading exercise formulation. Exercise 17.5 (a) in _QFT for the Gifted Amateur_ deals with a 0+1 dimensional system with Euclidean signature (where Euclidian time is called $x$), not a 1+1 dimensional system with Euclidean signature.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I quoted your comment in the EDIT of my answer, I don't know how to link you for more credit. Feel free to do that, if you wish

Answer (score 1):

The question seems okay to me. It's more or less giving you the time-independent Klein-Gordon equation for a 1D lattice, right?

I think a clarification on how to discretise the derivative would go miles on this question.

If you write 
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \frac{\phi_{j+\frac{1}{2}} - \phi_{j-\frac{1}{2}}}{a} 
$$
then you can easily just substitute the Fourier expansion they give you and use the Dirac delta function, which in discrete space is given by 
$$
\delta_{p,q} = \frac{1}{Na} \sum_j{e^{i(p-q)ja}}
$$

After cleaning everything up I think you get the end result.

Comment: Why would you use $j+\frac{1}{2}$ and $j−\frac{1}{2}$ as oppose to what I used in the squared expression of (3), which is my version of the discretized derivative?

Comment: They're somewhat equivalent. From a numerical methods point of view, the difference is you've got a forward difference derivative whereas I've used a central difference which generally has an increased order of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem doesn't make much sense as it stands. Without terms that include a time derivative, the system would just immediately jump the the configuration with the smallest $L$, as the speed with which it does so is not "punished" (does not increase the action).

In other words, the solution with the smallest action is the one with $L(t)=L_\text{min}$ at all times, except perhaps at $t=t_\text{initial}$.

In a sense though, $x$ and $t$ are just labels, so you could reinterpret your problem, considering $x$ as your time coordinate. $\mathcal L$ would be your Lagrangian and $L$ your action, just as your book says.

EDIT: The problem does actually talk about the *Lagrangian* $\mathcal L$. So this is not the Lagrangian density. Then $L$ is actually already your action. Also note what Qmechanic wrote in his comment, which I quote below for completeness

> The question (v5) seems to be caused by a somewhat misleading exercise
>   formulation. Exercise 17.5 (a) in QFT for the Gifted Amateur deals
>   with a 0+1 dimensional system with Euclidean signature (where
>   Euclidian time is called x), not a 1+1 dimensional system with
>   Euclidean signature.

Comment: so you're saying that in the case of a problem with just one variable, let's say $x$, the action is the integral of the Lagrangian over that one variable, even if that variable isn't time?

Comment: @Physics_Plasma: "Action" is defined as the integral of the Lagrangian over time. So to be technically correct, you would interpret $x$ as "time". Indeed, as Qmechanic points out in a comment to your question $x$ is indeed the time in your problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  The book explicitly mentions at some point that it will "follow convention" and call both $L$ and $\mathcal{L}$ "Lagrangians", so I didn't take its word choice in this question too literally when it didn't explicitly say "Lagrangian density".